# String to array when two comma to one array with php

Tags: php

my string has

```
$string = "apple,banana,orange,lemon";
```

I want to as

```
$array = [
           [apple,banana],
           [orange,lemon]
]
```

Comment: Any attempts? Maybe `explode` and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php or str_split, or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Try to come up with a design yourself and then ask about a specific piece you're struggling with. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is no obvious way of grouping nor an intention. Why are apple and banana to be grouped but not banana and orange?

Answer (score 1):

Use **array_chunk** in combination with **explode** defined in php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```php
<?php

    $string = "apple,banana,orange,lemon";
   
    $input_array = explode (",", $string);
   
    print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
?>
```

Will output as below:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => banana
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => orange
            [1] => lemon
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps you get on your way. To transform a string to an array, you can use

```
$elements = explode(',', $string);
```

This will leave you with this array: `($elements == [apple,banana,orange,apple])`

From there, you can build it the way you want, like:

```
$array[] = [$elements[0], $elements[1]];
$array[] = [$elements[2], $elements[3]];
```

This results in the array you are looking for, but this solution is only for the string you've given with four elements, separated by comma.

Comment: Wouldn't this give an associative array? OP wants to chunk the string/array at every other interval. `['apple'] = 'banana'` doesnt appear to be the intended result.

Comment: At first I thought that, than I saw the nested array and got confused. /fixed